# To call specific ant target in Maven

Tags: maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

Please find the below code snippet:-

```
    <plugins>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target name="test2">
            <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
            <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>

            <echo message="test classpath:    ${test_classpath}"/>
            <echo message="plugin classpath:  ${plugin_classpath}"/>
          </target>
     <target name="test1">
            <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
            <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>

            <echo message="compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}"/>
            <echo message="runtime classpath: ${runtime_classpath}"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and when i exceute "mvn compile", output of last target i.e. test1 comes. I have tried mvn compile -Dtarget="test2" and mvn compile -DantTarget="test2" but not able to call target "test2". Please help

Answer (score 1):

The maven ant-run plugin only supports a single target in its [configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html#target), but you can get the same effect by using [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Add the following to you pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile-test1</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target name="test1">
                                    <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                                    <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>

                                    <echo message="compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}"/>
                                    <echo message="runtime classpath: ${runtime_classpath}"/>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test2</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile-test2</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target name="test2">
                                    <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
                                    <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>

                                    <echo message="test classpath:    ${test_classpath}"/>
                                    <echo message="plugin classpath:  ${plugin_classpath}"/>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You can the invoke maven as `mvn -Ptest1` or `mvn -Ptest2` to activate one of the profiles and execute the chosen ant target.